# Header Opacity not working on pages

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have some weirdness happening here. I have created a custom WordPress theme and I am changing the opacity of my header element to opaque white when the user scrolls down the page using this piece of JavaScript in a JavaScript file I am calling bundled.min.js...

```
$(function($){
  if($(document).scrollTop() > 3){
    $('.header').addClass('dark');
  }
  // Add opacity class to the site header
  $(document).on('scroll', function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop() > 3){
      $('.header').addClass('dark');
    } else {
      $('.header').removeClass('dark')
    }
  });
});
```

And naturally some css targeting my header element that is located within my header.php file. 
The header.php file is also included in my front-page.php, page.php, single.php, index.php and all the other regular WordPress pages within my theme.

That said the problem I am facing is that the opacity scroll function only works on my front-page.php file and none of the other pages. I really cannot figure out why this is. Has anyone else come across this before?

Many thanks

Comment: What have you done to verify that this is not a caching issue?

Comment: Well its been like this for over a week now and I have not added any caching plugins, code or cdn's to it as it's on a demo beta site atm.

Comment: Just to rule out *browser* caching, verify that the issue persists in a different browser you haven't used in, at least, the last week (you can also check with a "Guest" user or using "Incognito" with Chrome, Ctrl+Shift+N). Do you find the code in question when you try to search for it in the source code on the pages you are experiencing this issue with?

Answer (score 0):

Seems I have fixed it! The JavaScript code was in a file with other Javascript functions specific to the front-page.php file so I created a new file called header.min.js and added the function there then added that file to my footer.php file!

There was obviously some conflict going on between the functions but all works as it should now with no errors happening!